# python xlrd convert xlsx to csv

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to convert excel files to csv files using `xlrd` library.

But I got this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0142' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`

Can it be because the excel file is too large? Cause everything works fine with excel files that have small number of rows. But when I tried to convert an excel file that has nearly 2000 rows, I got this error.

[UPDATE]

This is the code:

```
filepath = './attachments'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(filepath, 'result.xls'))
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
fp = open(os.path.join(filepath, 'result.csv'), 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for rownum in xrange(sheet.nrows):
  wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
fp.close()
```

And this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MethodTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0142' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are reading a Excel sheet with data outside of the ASCII range.

When writing unicode values to a CSV file, automatic encoding takes place, but for values outside the ASCII range of characters that fails. Encode explicitly:

```
for rownum in xrange(sheet.nrows):
      wr.writerow([unicode(val).encode('utf8') for val in sheet.row_values(rownum)])
```

On Python 3, the CSV module supports Unicode text, provided you provided the `open()` command with a suitable encoding and opened the file *in text mode*. While the default *can* be UTF-8, it is better to be explicit. The documentation recommends you use `newline=''` when opening a file for CSV writing:

```
fp = open(os.path.join(filepath, 'result.csv'), 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
      wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
```

You may need to pick a different encoding, depending on your needs.

It's also a good idea to use the file object as a context manager to make sure it is closed after the code exits (with or without an exception):

```
with open(os.path.join(filepath, 'result.csv'), 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
          wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Python 3 I get a TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @PatrickRuff: looks like you opened the file in binary mode, something I probably overlooked back in 2018 when I added a Python 3 section. I must've not been paying attention to what objects where involved. I've corrected the answer.